# How to correctly expand Excel formula if number of elements in sum must change when expanding?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very simple example to demonstrate (the core of) my problem. Please see the following table:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 1951 | TR-Price S&P 500 |
| 2 | 1950 |  | 150 |
| 3 | 1951 |  | 152 |
| 4 | 1952 |  | 151 |
| 5 | 1953 |  | 157 |
| 6 | 1954 |  | 155 |
| 7 | 1955 |  | 159 |
| 8 |  |  |  |
| 9 |  |  | yearly recurring investment |
| 10 |  |  | $1 |

The goal is to calculate the total portfolio size within the fields *B2 to B7*, based on the start year (*field B1*) and the end year (*fields A2 to A7*). It is assumed that a yearly recurring investment according to *field C10* is invested. This means I want a calculation of the compounded interest for all combinations of start year and end year, which result between *B2 and B7*. For example *field B6* would represent the investing period from 1951 to 1954. But there's not a constant rate of interest. Instead the effective rate for each year results from the TR-Price change in Column C for the corresponding years.

Examples for correct results:

- for field B2: *zero or n/a* (start year of investment later than end year)
- for field B3: *zero or n/a* (start year of investment equal than end year)
- for field B4: *$0.9934* ( calculation: $1 * 151/152, representing compunded interest from 1951 to 1952)
- for field B5: *$2,0726* ( calculation: $1 * (157/152 + 157/151), representing compunded interest from 1951 to 1953)

So as for field B4 the calculation could be done in Excel via:
`= $C$10 * ($C4/$C$3)` as there's only one year of compunded interest (from 1951 to 1952 => decrease of 152 to 151).
But for B5 the formula the calculation needs to be done with something like:
`= $C$10 * ($C5/$C$3 + $C5/$C$4)` as there is the first dollar, which obtains an increase by two years of compunded interest (from 152 to 157 during 1951 to 1953) and the second dollar, which obtains the latest year of compunded interest (from 151 to 157 during 1952 to 1953).

**Which brings me to my question:** How can implement this in a way that I only need to create a single *universal* formula - e.g. in *field B4* - which can then be expanded downwards? The problem is: the number of elements within the formula must change if the distance between start and end year changes. Is Excel capable of something like that or will I need some VBA Macro with a for loop?

Comment: This seems to be a delete / repeat of a previous question, wait while I look at it.

Comment: Please double check your example calculations. 1*(157/152) is *not* equal to $0.9934. also for the next cell would you use 157 twice?

Comment: Yes $0.9934 is 151/152 which is confusing

Comment: sorry, I replaced 157/152 by 151/152, which is correct. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to  your description above  you could use a pull-down formula like this in B2:

```
=IF(A2<=B$1,"",SUM(C2/INDEX(C$2:C$10,MATCH(B$1,A$2:A$10)):C1))
```

[image]

Comment: I changed / improved your formula a tiny bit that it correctly considers the field C10 for the recurrent investment and then it becomes:

`=IF($A2<=B$1,"", $C$10 * SUM($C2/INDEX($C$2:$C$7,MATCH(B$1,$A$2:$A$7)):$C1))`And I added the $ symbols correctly so that the table can be extended to the right side by different start years and still can be expanded to the right as well!

It works like a charm!!